# iOS document thumbnails with threads

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, thumbnails

I'm making an application that is similar to Pages for iOS, in that it has a scrolling list of documents with thumbnails. The issue I'm having:

What is the safe way to make thumbnails of these documents on a background thread?

Most of UIKit is not thread safe and will throw exceptions, so how can I make a thumbnail of stuff when the rendering APIs will throw exceptions while I render in the background? Is it a better idea to render on the main thread during idle time?

For the record, it will be a text document, so its not just rendering an image downsized in the background as I know how to do that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don’t you use UIDocumentBrowserViewController instead of reimplementing the collection view with thumbnails yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky for you, my friend, CoreGraphics is generally thread safe.  This little project [here](https://github.com/raphaelcruzeiro/PdfAnnotator-for-iPad) is dedicated to PDF annotation; but can be used to get the thumbnail of a specific page and return a UIImage.  It's quite fast, assuming you do one page per document, and all relevant code can be found in the class called `PDFThumbNailFactory`.

For safety's sake; I would return a CGImage, because UIImage is not thread safe.

Comment: Unfortunately, my documents are text only - as in .txt... Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: A snapshot of a UIWebView that you load in the background might work.  Bear in mind that UIWebView is notoriously antsy when it comes to UIGraphicsContexts.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Either that, or would setting the text on a UITextView and getting a snapshot of that? I'm gonna bet that its not going to like background threading however.

Comment: Yeah.  Unfortunately, I can only think of one dispatcheable option, and it makes me shudder to think of it. CoreText.  It's a MASSIVE and annoying framework, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the exact same thing. I've avoided CoreText quite a bit, accepting that I can't implement some features as the overhead for the rest of the framework is too intense. I'm going to look at idle time activity on the main thread as the thumbnails are low priority. There'll be placeholders, and then each thumbnail itself once created will persist on the filing system like Pages does this. Only once for each imported document will a thumbnail image ever be required to be drawn in this way. Thanks for the help, though mate.

Comment: No problem. Look into that link though, he has a very unique method of only loading the thumbnails of visible cells.

Comment: That little project there uses and UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() and doc's say it's not thread safe.

Comment: Doesn't mean he can't just nest a dispatch to the main thread and get around it.